# Driving a 50W LED from 10 rechargable batteries (XL6009 converter @25% efficinecy)

Tags: led, batteries, current, dc-dc-converter, constant-current

I want to power up for a few minutes a [50W LED](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00FGMO9HW/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1) (37V at 1.5A) from batteries. I have a bank of 10 NiMH rechargeable batteries (total of 12.9V), each in the 2.1-2.5Ah range.
I use a [DC-DC step up convertor with XL6009](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00HV59922/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1) to increase the voltage (made in China, 5euro, Amazon). 
[image]

*I KNOW that I need constant current not constant voltage! This is just an experiment to see if the batteries can keep up for 15 minutes or so.*

The convertor is sucking about 2A from the battery bank but it only outputs 0.22A 24V. Why? I was hoping for an output of at least 0.5A. The LED is bright but the radiator is not even getting warm.

The batteries can deliver OVER 4A in shortcut, for a short while.

**Summary:** the converter draws 10V*2A and outputs 24V*0.22A. Efficiency: 25%!

Comment: need specs for charger and LEDs

Comment: step up from what to what?

Comment: @Silvester the answer lies probably, as Tony said, in the specs of the converter.

Comment: Hi thank you all for support. I updated the question with link to the LED and converter. There are not so many parameters. Sorry.

Comment: no specs on this product. Beware and ask yourself why they are selling it for  Price:  CDN$ 3.75 & FREE Shipping

Comment: From similar searches on Amazon, products based on Chinese XL6009 chip in the depicted board format can convert only 15-25 Watts. So overloading it twice  (50W load) does not improve its functionality. See https://www.amazon.com/Gowoops-Converter-Voltage-Adjustable-Circuit/dp/B01GRIQBRY/ref=pd_day0_23_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=08X1E5J3KRTZW7FZYW3C

Comment: try 2 or battery packs and https://www.amazon.de/einstellbar-Schritt-Steigern-Leistung-liefern/dp/B008O13FLS/ref=pd_cp_201_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=3JTX915AKPP4NHXYW6T3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah. The usual "I did not consider conservation of energy" confusion:

The power flowing *into* your converter must be the same as coming out of it. Power, for DC current, is simply voltage · current.

If you want to step up voltage by a factor of \$\frac{37}{10\cdot 1.2}\approx3\$, then you'll inversely reduce the current supplied – so, to produce 0.5 A at 36V, your step up converter would have to draw 1.5 A. And that is probably far beyond its reach.

Also, your batteries only supplying 4A in shortcut is not a good sign. NiMh usually has much higher short circuit current. But in that case, the voltage drop at 1.5 A might already be large enough to inhibit operation.

**EDIT**: you picked a step-up converter that doesn't even have a maximum current or maximum transferred power specification. It's hence the most likely reason that you're trying to make your step-up converter source more current than it possibly can. Use a step-up converter that is either rated for the power you want to draw or the current at the voltage you want to draw.

Comment: The batteries are dropping from 12.9V to 10V at a current of 2A.

Comment: Then I doubt your 4A short circuit measurement.

Comment: The converter is already sucking 1.95A.

Comment: As stated in my question, the current in shortcut was "over 4A". More exactly was 4A as I started to measure and was increasing as the time lapsed. After 2 seconds was already 5A. I didn't wanted to overload the batteries so I stopped the measurement after 2-3 seconds. I don't know exaclty how much I can safely keep the shortcut. But tomorrow I can try again for 10 seconds.

Comment: Don't! There's folks on this forum that have burnt multiple multimeter fuses by shorting batteries.

Comment: Shorting the batteries for 10 seconds shortens life cycles due to temperature rise.

Comment: I have found the specs (PDF) for two ICs both made in China. Both fail to show the maximum I/O current. China-quality electronics :)

Comment: I agree with you. I have found the specs (PDF) for two ICs both made in China. Both fail to show the maximum I/O current. China-quality electronics :) It seems that the efficiency of the converter is not even 50% (draws 20W, outputs about 5W). They state up to 95% efficiency.

Comment: I claimed lack of documentation/bad product specifications and got a refund from Amazon (do this on eBay if you can :) )